# number_format inside foreach loop with if statements

Tags: php, numbers, format

I have three columns of data coming in from a form. My goal is to add decimal places to each entry if the fields are left blank. For example, I have BMI, height, and weight. BMI will have one decimal place if the form field is left blank, resulting in 0.0. For weight, it will be 0.00 and so on.

Here is the code I have now which handles the BMI form field:

```
$return['is_spouse'] = ($return['is_spouse'] == 1) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    if($biometric_data) {
        foreach(self::$biometric_fields as $column_name) {
            if($column_name == 'bmi') {
                $biometrics[$column_name] = number_format($bio[$column_name], 1);
                continue;
            }
            $biometrics[$column_name] = $bio[$column_name];
        }
    }
```

When attempting to add the height or weight parts to the code, BMI becomes a blank result and the number format gets applied to the height only, as if that section of the code gets skipped.

```
$return['is_spouse'] = ($return['is_spouse'] == 1) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    if($biometric_data) {
        foreach(self::$biometric_fields as $column_name) {
            if($column_name == 'bmi') {
                $biometrics[$column_name] = number_format($bio[$column_name], 1);
                continue;
            }
            $biometrics[$column_name] = $bio[$column_name];
        }
    }

    $return['is_spouse'] = ($return['is_spouse'] == 2) ;
    if($biometric_data) {
        foreach(self::$biometric_fields as $column_name) {
            if($column_name == 'height') {
                $biometrics[$column_name] = number_format($bio[$column_name], 2);
                continue;
            }
            $biometrics[$column_name] = $bio[$column_name];
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think you might need to provide some example data e.g. `$biometric_data`, `self::$biometric_fields` and your expected and current output of `$biometrics` - hard to say what's going wrong at this stage

Comment: It is unclear (to me) what you want to achieve and what the actual code you provide does otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You have two `foreach` loops, so on the second one it resets the 'bmi' field when it runs this:

```
$biometrics[$column_name] = $bio[$column_name];
```

You need to consolidate the two loops into one:

```
foreach(self::$biometric_fields as $column_name) {
        if($column_name == 'height') {
            $biometrics[$column_name] = number_format($bio[$column_name], 2);
            continue;
        } else if($column_name == 'bmi') {
            $biometrics[$column_name] = number_format($bio[$column_name], 1);
            continue;
        }
        $biometrics[$column_name] = $bio[$column_name];
    }
```